# Connect to MongoDB atlas cluster with flask-mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to connect with mongodb atlas from my flask app using flask-mongoengine.

```
DB_URI =  "mongodb+srv://flask_app_user:flask_app_user@cluster0.6jwadcx5g.mongodb.net/flask_app?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'replace_me_32437264278642')
    app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
        'host': os.environ.get('MONGODB_URI', DB_URI)
    }
    MongoEngine(app)
    socketio.init_app(app)
    SSLify(app)

    return app
```

But I am getting an error,

```
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme: URI must begin with 'mongodb://'
```

How can I use mongo atlas with flask_mongoengine?
I don't want to stick with flask_mongoengine. I don't want to change that.

Answer (score 1):

It worked correctly for me with the latest version `flask_mongoengine-1.0.0` and `pymongo-3.11.2`

It seems you're using the host from `MONGODB_URI` env var...
What do you have in `MONGODB_URI`??
Could you share also which version are you using?